# Solving huge dense square symmetric linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, linear-system, hardware

I have a linear system of the type

$A x = y$

where A is a dense, square, symmetric, positive definite matrix, $x$ a vector of unknown parameters, and $y$ is a vector of observed quantity.
I know that using a Cholesky decomposition based algorithm should be the fastest way to find the values of $x$ that fulfil the equation.
The only problem is I would like to do so for a matrix $A$ with dimension 500000x500000, and $x$ and $y$ 500000x1.
Is there any scientific computing library to do so? Which kind of hardware should I use?

Comment: Well I can tell you it is doable - on 16384 cores of a modern cluster a collaborator and I have demonstrated finding all evals and evecs of a dense, real, symmetric matrix of about that size which is a somewhat tougher calculation than you need. We used ScaLAPACK which also has solvers in, being the distributed memory version of LAPACK. So it is possible, but whether ScaLAPACK is a good way to go for your problem I feel less sure - hence a comment rather than an answer (basically I do diagonlisation, I rarely solve equations)

Comment: You're going to need a system with a lot of memory to even store the matrix A.  Multiply 500000 by 500000 by 8 bytes per entry and you'll have 2000 gigabytes of storage required for A.  This isn't something you can do on a desktop machine, but could well be within the capacity of a high performance computing cluster.

Comment: But even if possible, it seems questionable whether whatever you are doing is really best described by a dense matrix!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth why questionable? I can think of numerous problems that are really best described by a dense matrix.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks! ScaLAPACK seems a good start!

Comment: @pinpon I also can think of many systems that are most easily and efficiently expressed as dense matrices at small size, but as the size increases they become increasingly sparse - and as such I would spend some time checking that a dense solver really is the most appropriate in this case. This is what I think is Wolfgang's point, and also part of my hesitation in giving an answer.

Comment: @BrianBorchers You're missing a division by 2 because $A$ is symmetric (but that doesn't change the conclusion).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @IanBush I can also think of systems whose sparseness increase with the size of the problem. However, I can also think of systems that are not sparse at all and might not be easily approximated by a sparse system.

Comment: Why not use an iterative solver? You have an SPD matrix, conjugate gradient method should do the trick if your matrix is reasonably conditioned.

Comment: What is your science application?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Huge GNSS network adjustment